# How to unfreeze Linux Mint 20.3 (Ctrl+Alt+F10 induced)

Tags: linux-mint, freeze

My Linux Mint froze - no keyboard/mouse inputs visible, nothing after I accidentally pressed either Ctrl+Alt+F10 or Ctrl+shift+Alt+F10. I used the power button on my laptop to reboot (Restart fixes 90% of computer issues). It rebooted into the login screen, but 4 things were off.

1. My external monitor didn't have the login on it, just the background (it usually does as it is the primary monitor)
2. The password input cursor was blinking slower than usual
3. The mouse cursor wasn't moving
4. The moment I press ANY key or move my mouse it completely freezes
   I have googled around and fount that in Ubuntu Ctrl+Alt+F10 switches terminals, and Ctrl+Alt+F2 should work to fix it. It didn't.
   What happened and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Back to normal with Ctrl Alt F7:

Well explained there:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1167144

Comment: Ive tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Ow, strange !  
Did you try with another keyboard ?
To exit more gracefully that the power off, there is the Alt-SysReq sequence REISUB who is carefull reboot  (  see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key )

Comment: It looked like a complete freeze, and me being a Windows user previously, I just did a hard reset. I ended up "solving" the issue by doing a full re-install of Mint.